# Gem for Send/ Receive e-mails in Rails 4 admin panel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

Basically, I am searching for advise to choose best gem for **Sending/Receiving e-mails in Rails 4 admin panel**. Main requirement would be that gem can't be for specific domain e-mails like Gmail, Yahoo and etc.

At this moment I found **[mikel/mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail)**
What you think of this gem ? Or can you suggest better one ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [actionmailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html), which will already by bundled with your Rails installation. Integration with your Rails app would be easier with `actionmailer` than any 3rd party gems, since that's what it was designed for.

Comment: I was thinking that actionmailer is just for sending e-mails not receiving them. Thanks for advise.

Comment: `actionmailer` can parse received emails, see [this section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#receiving-emails) of the aforementioned guide.

Comment: The only downside is that `actionmailer` needs an external email server to receive emails. You could use a combination of `mikel/mail` and `actionmailer` for receiving emails. The data flow could look like `pop3 server > mikel/mail > rails`